# Error building VirtualBox PCI pass-through kernel module

Tags: linux, fedora, virtualbox, kernel-modules, make

I am using Fedora 32 with Kernel 5.7.10-201. I have installed updates yesterday and now my VirtualBox stopped working. I have tried to remove and reinstall Virtualbox and it is failing when I try to run setup to build the kernel modules using:

```
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

The output of this is:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.
```

and the contents of `/var/log/vbox-setup.log` is:

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Building the net filter module.
Building the net adaptor module.
Building the PCI pass-through module.
Error building the module:
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Since the output of the log file does not give much information I am stuck here. How do I solve this error?

Comment: Uninstall, reboot into an older kernel, then try reinstalling. Since Fedora uses the latest bleeding-edge kernel, it's very possible that VB doesn't know how to build it.

Comment: I already tried doing that but I still get the same error any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm..but it *did* work at one point, correct? Check on the VB site and see if there's a beta release out that you can try.

Comment: Yes it was working before I updated. I started wondering if there was an issue with the update transaction and that is what causing all this. I tried to rollback to another transaction but fails to do that complaining that there are some packages it cannot find to install (which are packages for FC31). Btw I am using the latest VirtualBox version, just re checked the website.

Comment: Unless you have a clean point to roll back to, you may need to reinstall the OS...maybe even back to FC31, if that was working. Another option is to try another VM solution like VMware Player or QEMU.